# Problems with setting up proxy for chrome using selenium 3.8.1

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, proxy

I used to set up proxy on chrome like in a code below, but when i updated to selenium 3.8.1 proxy stops working, i dont get any errors it just doesn't use proxy server and i dont know why. My chromedriver is also up to date.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=192.99.55.120:3128')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
driver.get("http://google.com/")
```

Would like to receive any advice, maybe alternative way to set up proxy for chromedriver.

Comment: Update the question with the error you are seeing.

Comment: i told that i don't get ANY errors

Answer (score 5):

If someone still interested, this is how i have finally solved the problem

```
from selenium.webdriver import Proxy
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver as ChromeDriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

settings = {
        "httpProxy": "192.99.55.120:3128",
        "sslProxy": "192.99.55.120:3128"
    }
proxy = Proxy(settings)

cap = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
cap['platform'] = "WINDOWS"
cap['version'] = "10"
proxy.add_to_capabilities(cap)

driver = ChromeDriver(desired_capabilities=cap, executable_path='C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
```

Comment: this answer could be improved by explaining what the issue was

Comment: i don't really know what the was the problem, i assume that in new  version of selenium chrome_options=options doesn't work at all, so instead of using webdriver.ChromeOptions() i was using DesiredCapabilities and Proxy from selenium.webdriver

Comment: Thanks for the solution, you really made my day!

Answer (score 3):

try

```
options.add_argument('--proxy-server="http=192.99.55.120:3128;https=192.99.55.120:3128"')
```

also try running your chrome binary directly with these params to see whether it works or not

```
chrome.exe --proxy-server="http=192.99.55.120:3128"
```

Comment: Great answer, specifically providing `http=<IP>:<PORT>` worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If  the navigator asks for the credentials username and password for the proxy and you need to handle this : (only if the alert come up)

```
driver.get("http://username:password@google.com/")
```