# Using proxy with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, proxy

I'm trying to use a proxy with selenium in python, but none of the ways I've tried worked, chrome is trying to reach the website without success.
I'm using proxy from https://free-proxy-list.net/

```
executable_path = r"C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\WebScrape\chromedriver75.exe"
proxy_address = "94.230.148.233:61576"

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--proxy-server=" + proxy_address)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=executable_path, options=chrome_options)
driver.set_page_load_timeout(60)
driver.get("https://whatismyipaddress.com/")
```

I also tried changing the page timeout, without succes.

Answer (score 0):

Try with http, so

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--proxy-server=http://94.230.148.233:61576")
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after hours of searching, I finally found a solution, looking at here: [Problems with setting up proxy for chrome using selenium 3.8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48411823/problems-with-setting-up-proxy-for-chrome-using-selenium-3-8-1)